# add "&" before redirect command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csh

now, I have a script using redirect command.

```
set filename1='/home/1.log'

echo "hello " >>& ${filename1}
```

Question:

1. I know "&" is added before file handler, but here, "filename1" is a file name, is it necessary to add "&" before this variable?
2. If not, does this "&" operator have some other meaning?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C shell, `>&` and `>>&` redirect both standard output and standard error to the designated file.

Note that Csh and derivatives are incompatible with Bourne shell; you should probably consider switching to a standard shell. These days, Bash and Zsh by and large support the same features as Tcsh, without sacrificing syntactic backwards compatibility with Bourne shell. See also http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Comment: Ugh, `>&`, kill it with fire. +1 though. :)

Comment: absolutely, i used the Csh. But, in the script file, there is also a line like "echo "hello " > ${filename1}". It works. I don't why these two style both works.